Set-Cookie is being set on redirection in ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7.2 . Why?
I am setting SameSite in Startup.Auth.cs like this:
CookiePath = "/; SameSite=Lax",

But for Login action, on redirection; the Set-Cookie value is being automatically set by the framework and not by code. The issue is that the Set-Cookie that is a response header has .AspNet.ApplicationCookie as its value. This is a very big vulnerability as the cookie is being exposed as part of response.
This is the state that I am getting for redirected Login action with HTTPResponseCode 302:
Set-Cookie is having .AspNet.ApplicationCookie
How to avoid/disable this vulnerability?
As described in the question, the scenario is to be avoided.

Have you tried debugging your code with redirection, you might be traversing the same code twice because of redirection
